# Soundcloud API for uploading files has stopped working with 401 error

Tags: soundcloud

I'm not exactly sure when this stopped working, but until recently my application had no trouble uploading tracks to Soundcloud. Now, after uploading a track (using POST), I get a 401 unauthorized response from the server. The file *has* actually been uploaded successfully, and I can see it on the user's home page.

Additionally, I am not getting error messages for any other interactions such as authorizing etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well I can't post a comment about the previous answer from **Ashish Chaturvedi** because I don't have enough reputation, so I'll have to do it here.

The problem is definitely not to do with my access token. I can use the exact same token to successfully carry out all sorts of other tasks.

This code has been working for years without trouble. It stopped working very recently. Something server side has changed.

Also, as I said in my original post, even though the server returns an error, the audio file in fact get successfully uploaded.

Comment: May be you are write but SoundCloud doesn't publish any changes logs . Thats you need to check your code again and wait for soundcloud support.

Answer (score 0):

As per SoundCloud docs

**401 Unauthorized**

```
This means that we were not able to authenticate you based on the information provided in the request. Make sure you're sending a client_id or an access_token.

Our public endpoints will work by just providing a client_id. Acting on behalf of another user is different. The Authentication section gives a detailed explanation of how this works.

If you're connecting using OAuth, don't forget that tokens can expire. These will need to be refreshed. Not doing so can also result in getting a 401 error.

If you need to check your application's details, use the Your Applications page. This will include the client_id for your application.
```

Its all depending on how you generated the access token, one of two things are happening:

- You are not sending the correct access token.
- The access token you are sending has expired.

If it's 2, you should have gotten a refresh token when the user authorizes your app. The PHP SoundCloud SDK has a accessTokenRefresh() method that you can use in this scenario.